# How do i call "recall" method?

Tags: java, computer-science

Please tell me how to call `recall` method.
I am new in Java.
I am making a program to display prime and composite number.

```java
package composite;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class composite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("press number till you want composite number & prime numbers");
        int m=p.nextInt();int g[]=new int [m+1];prime(m);
        for(int k=4;k<=m;k++)
        {

            for(int b=2;b<k;b++){
                if(k%b==0){

                    g[k]=k;break;
                }
            }
        }

        }

    public static int prime(int m){
        int e[]= new int[m+1];
        for(int i=2;i<m;i++)
        {
            int p=0;
            for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                p=1;
            }
            if(p==0)
                e[i]=i;
        }return(m);
    }
    public static int recall(int m, int [] e, int [] g){
        for(int a=1;a<m;a++){
            System.out.println(e[a]+" "+g[a]);
        }
        return m;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following and modify the variables accordingly :

```
Composite call_recall = new Composite();
int recall_value = recall(m,e,g);
```

Place the proper values as you require in place of m, e and g.